# Jenkins build fails when running nodeJS

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have Jenkins set up on a machine with the NodeJS plugin. Sadly, whenever I try to use the plugin in a build, it fails with:

```
[workspace] $ node /tmp/hudson3477900862350780409.js
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory          
"/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/XXX/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

When I log into the machine as the jenkins user, I can use node through command line. I also added the path to node (`/opt/node-0.6.18/bin`) into the Configuration screen for the current working node (which is only one: master).

I've been stuck with this for a while, any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you get when you type `which node` logged in to the machine as a jenkins user? It's possible that the node binary is not found the `PATH` when run inside the jenkins task. I'd try using the full path to node (typically `/usr/local/bin/node` or something) and see if you see the same error.

Comment: I get 'usr/bin/node' when using that command. I  thought about using the full path, but I can't find anywhere where that's configurable for the nodeJS plugin. I did found a workaround that'll post now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, this isn't the most elegant of solutions, but it worked: I simply made a symlink to from /bin/ to the installation path for node and now the problem's gone.

Comment: To create a symlink you can use e.g. "cd /usr/bin"     "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node"

Comment: I had to symlink `npm` as well, so `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /bin/npm`

Answer (score 4):

ah easy, you need to tick "Provide Node/npm bin folder to PATH" when running a "execute shell" build task"

Comment: Though on a later Jenkins version... - is there necessity to do something like it in Jenkins ver. 2.190.1 ? If yes, how can I do it? I don't see a tickbox, after having installed the NodeJS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I am using NVM and I had the same issue. One workaround was to create a symlink:

```
ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node /bin/node
ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm /bin/npm
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins running in Docker, use jenkins/jenkins:latest image to avoid this issue.

Answer (score -4):

the error came up just because you did't install node in your machine.after you installed it,and add it to PATH,then the problem can be solved.
hope it helps.